# jquery - dynamically set a height or width when animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I was curious on how to set a height or width dynamically based on when a div is animated.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div1dimensions = 50 / 180 +'px';  
  $("#div1").animate({
    width: divdimensions,
    height: "100px",
    opacity: 1,
  }, 1500 );
});
```

Can I not just create a variable and place it where the width or height is? Or is that only for CSS values such as 100px?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can Refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674068/jquery-animate-height-with-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that is important is that when using the object form of the `.css()` method, any numerical values placed there are inherently assumed to be pixel values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div1dimensions = (50 / 180);  

  $("#div1").animate({
    width: div1dimensions,
    height: 100,
    opacity: 1,
  }, 1500 );
});
```

Notice the lack of quotation marks. If you go about it this way, you can use a variable very easily:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div1dimensions = (50 / 180),
      divHeight = div1dimensions * 1.5;  

  $("#div1").animate({
    width: divdimensions,
    height: divHeight,
    opacity: 1,
  }, 1500 );
});
```

Or any other variable calculation you wish, this is just an example. Additionally, as-of jQuery 1.4 you can pass in a function for that calculation. The example used in the [jQuery .css() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) modified to reflect your example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div1dimensions = (50 / 180);  

  $("#div1").animate({
    width: div1dimensions,
    height: function(i){
        return i * 50;
    },
    opacity: 1,
  }, 1500 );
});
```

That one can get tricky pretty quickly, and is really only helpful in very specific scenarios, but is handy when needed.

Comment: Thank you. One note, you might want to edit your width: divdimensions to div1dimensions. Also, if I wanted to write 50 divided by 100 and then multiple that value by 180, is it correct to write (50 / 100 * 180)? thanks again.

Comment: technically yes, however i hate implicit code (which that code is implicitly relying on order of operations). personally i would write that as `((50 / 100) * 180)`. this is encased appropriately, and clearly denotes the order of execution mathematically.